# Recurrence Relations by Substitution Method?

Tags: substitution, recurrence, induction

I have:
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8) + cn; c > 0.

This is my induction step: 
Want to prove T(n) is in O(n), i.e. some d > 0 and n0 so that every n > n0 and T(n) < dn

T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8) + cn <= d(n/4) + d(n/4) + d (n/8) + cn = dn(7/8) + cn
= dn(7/8) + cn <= dn
...
= 8c <= d

I get stuck for the base case but this is how my teacher explained it to me:
Base case: need n0 to be small enough so that it is try.
Try n0 = 8
T(8) = T(4) + T(2) + T(1) + c8 <= 8T(4) + 8T(2) + 8T(1) + C8 < d8

Can somebody explain the base case to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for base case `T(8)`, we can assume that the operations are finite. so the running time would be `O(1)`(constant time). because you can count the number of operations.